# Jupyter lab startup stuck on macOS

Tags: python, jupyter-lab

I try to start Jupyter lab on macOS Catalina. I have downloaded and installed the latest version from Anaconda3. Writing `jupyter lab` in a terminal window starts up the kernel, but in the Safari browser progress stops at the splash screen. After some time the message to either **wait more** or **clear workspace** pops up. Neither button leads to any further progress. All I can do is stop the kernel in the terminal with ^C. Has anybody had the same problem and could fix it? The Jupyter installation must be in principle ok, since the command `jupyter notebook` in the terminal window starts the classical jupyter notebook interface in the browser correctly.

Comment: Did you find a solution to your issue?